# Prepopulate file upload form in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I am working on a struts 2 web application where user can upload file through a file upload form, if the file already exists in database, a confirmation message should be displayed to overwrite the existing file or cancel the action.

On upload the database is queried for that file and if it exists the action results and set a flag in session which shows the jquery dialog box for user confirmation. I need to implement continue button in the dialog box which will set another flag to specify overwrite and call the same action again, this time the file will be uploaded. To implement this I need to prefill the file upload input box with previous request parameter before calling the upload action.

Is there any other method to implement the above requirement?

Please let me know in case any details are required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know of, you can NOT prefil a file input box in any browser with a file from the user's drive, as this can lead to some serious security issues.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684013/is-it-possible-to-re-populate-a-file-select-form-field-with-what-the-user-previou Getting the file to your server and saving is as a temp file would be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you dont want to upload a file if a file with same filename exists in the database. If this is the case, why dont you check for the duplicity of filenames as soon as a file is selected to upload. This can be done in two ways

1. load list of all the filenames along with the page and check the selected filename with this list
2. Use **ajax** to send request to server for checking for duplicate filename when a file is selected

You can use the `onchange` event of the `file` element

For security reasons, you cannot mess with the `value` attribute of the `file` element programatically, otherwise you could fill-in any file from the user's system and submit the form

Comment: very bad solution is to load all file names, second one sounds like ok solution.

Comment: Yes, but in my application i have to check for duplicate filenames(images) in a patient case. And each case cannot have more than **5** images, so in that case it is not such a bad idea

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually whether the file will be uploaded or not is decided based on file content, so it cannot be decided until the file is uploaded. However, I have given up trying to prefill the file upload field, instead I am working on the method to store the previously uploaded file in temp directory and pass the filename in request to the JSP. If user choose to overwrite, the temp file will be uploaded. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Accepted answer, as manipulating value of file upload field is not the correct way to implement the solution and also not possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get user confirmation before sending the request by a checkbox asking whether to overwrite if the file exists. Then in your action do your IO stuff.

But if you still want to show the confirmation after sending the request I suggest you to use a custom interceptor that passes the request on both conditions of user confirmation and existence of the file. If the check didn't pass, you can return a custom result for confirmation part and resubmit the request. Just an idea.