# Django: How to prepopulate file upload path with current file path?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

I have a modelform that my views generate an HTML form for editing content. Currently, it's able to pull in the current stored text content, like this:

```
@login_required
def edit_person(request, s_id, p_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Person, id=p_id)

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = PersonForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            p.name = request.POST['name']
            p.title = request.POST['title']
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['photo'], request.FILES['photo'].name, 'media/images/people/')
            p.photo = request.FILES['photo']
            p.order = request.POST['order']  
            p.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/section/'+s_id+'/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("error")

    else:
        form = PersonForm({ 'name': p.name, 'title': p.title, 'photo': p.photo, 'order': p.order })
        return render_to_response('auth/edit-form.html', { 'form': form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/section/'+s_id+'/')
```

However, the photo file path is blank. I don't want the user to have to upload a new file every time they edit something if they don't want to change the image. How do I get the file upload field to appear pre-populated and not overwrite itself if they don't change it? Thanks.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684013/is-it-possible-to-re-populate-a-file-select-form-field-with-what-the-user-previou for a brief explanation about why this cannot be done.

Comment: @George Cummins - Ok, that makes sense. I guess my next question is, how do I get the form to validate if upload field is left blank? I'm trying to tell it to overwrite the file only if the user has uploaded one, if not, use what was previously there. I'm getting a MultiValueDictKeyError

Comment: use `p.save(commit=False)` go through the documentation of `save()` [1]:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: @Pannu - thanks! Totally worked!

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, it *can* be done! However, it requires the use of a custom django app called [django-file-resubmit](https://github.com/un1t/django-file-resubmit)

Note that app as given **only works for the widgets in admin and requires sorl-thumbnail**.

You may prefer to use my fork:

https://github.com/JordanReiter/django-file-resubmit

It's a general-purpose version for use everywhere a ModelForm is used that doesn't have any other prerequisites.

It's pretty cool in that it automagically stores the file on submission (even if there is a validation error) and retrieves it from the cache when the widget is rendered in the form.

This is literally all you have to do to implement it:

```
import file_resubmit.widgets

class PersonForm:
    """ existing code here """
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=file_resubmit.widgets.ResubmitImageWidget())
```

Comment: Note that this uploads files to your server whether the rest of the form is valid or not, and then caches them for later. If for some reason you don't want to do that at all until the rest of the form is validated, then this version won't work.